# SyntaxError: Unexpected token { when trying to export a class in es5 module for use in another module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Any ideas how the error is occuring? The class looks to be declared ok ..

car.js

```
function Car() {}

Car.prototype.setNumberOfWheels(numberOfWheels) {
    this.numberOfWheels = numberOfWheels;
}

Car.prototype.print() {
    console.log(this);
}

module.exports.Car = Car;
```

server.js

```
const model = require('./model.js');
```

Error:

```
Car.prototype.setNumberOfWheels(numberOfWheels) {
                                                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/bob/git/project/server.js:2:15)
```

Comment: this.number of wheels, where are you calling the variable from?

Comment: That's not the correct way to define a method.

Comment: That line is in fact a syntax error. If you want to make that property a function, you have to do it in an assignment expression with a function instantiation expression on the right.

Comment: Yes, looking at @omri_saadon answer, I realise I missed ` = function()` when declaring the functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare `setNumberOfWheels` and `print` as a functions.

```
Car.prototype.setNumberOfWheels = function(numberOfWheels) {
    this.numberOfWheels = numberOfWheels;
}

Car.prototype.print = function() {
    console.log(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The right way to declare a method using the [shorthand syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) (on objects initializers) is:

```
var car = {}
```

Then to add methods,

```
Car.prototype.setNumberOfWheels = numberOfWheels => {
    this.numberOfWheels = numberOfWheels;
}

Car.prototype.print = () => {
    console.log(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ecmascript-5 you have to define *setNumberOfWheels*  and *print* as functions ( [see prototype examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype#Examples) )

```
function Car() {}

Car.prototype.setNumberOfWheels = function(numberOfWheels) {
    this.numberOfWheels = numberOfWheels;
}

Car.prototype.print= function() {
    console.log(this);
}

module.exports.Car = Car;
```

You can use [ES6 Classes](http://es6-features.org/#ClassDefinition)

```
class Car {
    setNumberOfWheels(numberOfWheels) {
        this.numberOfWheels = numberOfWheels;
    }
    print() {
        console.log(this);
    }
}


module.exports.Car = Car;
```

Comment: This is specifically tagged [tag:ecmascript-5].